# how to solve this markov chain problem?

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-process

This is a problem in the book of "introduction to stochastic process ". Any help to solve this problem ??
[image]

Comment: where to add a working hyperlink ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P$ is the one-step transition matrix and $P_k$ is the k-step transition matrix then

$
P_k = P^k.
$

You are looking to do the calculation for $k = 3$.

Comment: so I have to calculate P^3 and see state(0,1) or state (1,1) ?

Comment: yes I know, it is not a homework, I'm learning by myself and it is out of my domain so sorry for this question because I will do my best to learn all this soon as possible. thank you stants.